# Ansible new user changes ansible tmp directory

Tags: ansible

I have a piece of ansible script which was running fine.

```
  user:
    name:     "{{ item['name'] }}"
    password: "{{ item['password'] }}"
    group:   "{{ item['group'] }}"
    groups:   "{{ item['groups'] }}"
    uid:      "{{ item['uid'] }}"
  with_items:
    - { name: perf, password: "{{ user_perf_pwd }}", group: "perf",   groups: "perf", uid: 23564 }
    - { name: ora,   password: "{{ user_ora_pwd }}",   group: "ora",     groups: "ora",          uid: 9965 }
```

The first user gets created as expected. The second user fails with the following error stating that tmp is not accessible.

```
"msg": "Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. 
Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. 
Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /home/perf/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /home/perf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1619654689.74-17782-45103910875996 `\" 
&& echo ansible-tmp-1619654689.74-17782-45103910875996=\"` echo /home/perf/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1619654689.74-17782-45103910875996 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}], "warnings": ["The input password appears not to have been hashed. The 'password' argument must be encrypted for this module to work properly."]
```

Why is the ansible temp directory changed to `/home/perf` after a new user is created?

Comment: Before anything  else, I would first take care of this: `warnings": ["The input password appears not to have been hashed. The 'password' argument must be encrypted for this module to work properly` => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-encrypted-passwords-for-the-user-module

Comment: I fixed that warning, but this issue still exists.